# Start a separate powershell or cmd and reuse it whenever I need during the initial script

Tags: powershell, interop

I'm writing a script that, among other things, will have to run, in a separate cmd/ps shell, a command line sip-client which will connect / register to a sip trunk circuit, after that, the sip-client have to stay opened in background in a "listen mode" state.
After this action, the initial script have to runs others stuff, at a certain point I've to "re-use" the separate shell where I've launched the sip-client, for making a call to a phone number...

How can I re-use and runs commands in the separate cmd/ps shell whenever I need it?

Comment: This is a fairly broad question. You would need a combination of `PSSessions` and `ThreadJobs` (I don't believe `PSSessions` will survive marshalling between processes)

Comment: `powershell.exe -noexit -file script.ps1`. Then run commands later when you feel like it in that window.

Comment: @AdminOfThings That only works if you are interactively wanting to reuse the other session. Programmatically, you can't (without some serious hoop jumping) regain control of the child powershell process

Comment: @BendertheGreatest Sure but that wasn't stated as a requirement.

Comment: Damn you for being technically correct, the best kind of correct

Comment: I am sure what you are talking about is probably what the poster is looking for. However, that's a lot of rabbit hole coding if we go by assumptions alone.

Comment: "That's a lot of rabbit hole coding" exactly why I stated this is a fairly broad question. But if you just wanted to do it interactively, then you are correct and it's a straightforward solution as long as you don't need to automate the child session(s) beyond the first invocation. I suppose we should hope OP will clear up this impasse.

Comment: @AdminOfThings and @ BendertheGreatest, Hi! Unfotunately I need to make this script for testing (every 10 min.) the flow of a mini ivr system... need batch approach!

Comment: While the separate command-line sip client is in listen mode are you actually able to use it to make a call also?  Or do you really need to run a separate instance of the sip client to make the call?

Comment: @Daniel Hi Daniel, the [sip-client](https://github.com/pjsip/pjproject) is a command line binary, I run it from PS or cmd with some switch options and, once it's launched, it waits for a new command to execute its work, like make new call, send dtmf, etc . not need to be re-spawned or re-launched. I hope I have answered to your question!

Comment: Ok, thanks.  So the question then still is after the script does it's other work and then returns to the sip client, do you need the script to interact with the sip client (i.e., do you need the script to make the call) or will this be done manually?  I believe once the binary is running powershell can no longer interact with it.  You may need to look into sending keystrokes using wscript.shell or AutoIt